# Find data from one table that is larger than the data in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that specifies the date of employees' daily leave. I also have another table that specifies the date employees arrive at work. How to find out which employee entered at work when he went on leave.

`LeaveTable` that shows Employee leave date table looks like this:

| id | EmpName | EmpFamily | EmpFatherName | LeaveDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | karim | mansoory | ali | 1400/01/02 |
| 2 | majid | ghasemi | hasan | 1400/02/03 |
| 3 | hasan | hamidi | bagher | 1400/02/10 |
| 4 | hasan | hamidi | bagher | 1400/03/15 |
| 5 | majid | ghasemi | hasan | 1400/03/15 |
| 6 | yaser | akbary | ahmad | 1400/03/17 |
| 7 | hosssein | mohammadi | jasem | 1400/03/18 |
| 8 | yaser | akbary | ahmad | 1400/04/02 |
| 9 | karim | mansoory | ali | 1400/04/11 |
| 10 | karim | mansoory | ali | 1400/04/18 |
| 11 | yaser | akbary | ahmad | 1400/05/02 |

`EnterTable` Table showing the date of arrival of employees to the main warehouse of the office looks like this:

| id | EmpName | EmpFamily | EmpFatherName | EnterDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | farzane | ahmadi | jafar | 1400/01/02 |
| 2 | majid | ghasemi | hasan | 1400/02/04 |
| 3 | nima | alimi | saber | 1400/02/10 |
| 4 | akram | gheibi | ahmad | 1400/03/17 |
| 5 | hosssein | mohammadi | jasem | 1400/03/19 |
| 6 | kabir | sabry | abed | 1400/04/10 |
| 7 | yaser | akbary | ahmad | 1400/01/07 |

I want this result

| id | EmpName | EmpFamily | EmpFatherName | LeaveDate | EnterDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | majid | ghasemi | hasan | 1400/02/03 | 1400/02/04 |
| 2 | hosssein | mohammadi | jasem | 1400/03/18 | 1400/03/19 |
| 3 | yaser | akbary | ahmad | 1400/05/02 | 1400/01/07 |

My SQL code is:

```
  Select
      LeaveTable.EmpName,
      LeaveTable.EmpFamily,
      LeaveTable.EmpFatherName,
      LeaveTable.LeaveDate ,
      EnterTable.EnterDate 
  from
        LeaveTable
        left outer join EnterTable
            on LeaveTable.EmpName=EnterTable.EmpName and
               LeaveTable.EmpFamily=EnterTable.EmpFamily and
               LeaveTable.EmpFatherName=EnterTable.EmpFatherName
            where EnterTable.EnterDate>LeaveTable.LeaveDate
    order by 
        EmpName,EmpFamily,EmpFatherName,EnterTable.EnterDate,LeaveTable.LeaveDate
```

But above codes has error.
Can every body help me?

Comment: *above codes has error*... which is what? And what sort of date is `1400/01/02`?

Comment: @Stu those are islamic dates

Comment: But WHICH rows from LeaveTable should be included? Karim has multiple rows with different dates - you pick the "first" one shown in your sample data (and note that rows in a table have no position). Why? The same thought applies to EnterTable. I might guess what the appropriate logic should be but I do not because YOU need to define that logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY min(e.id)), 
  e.EmpName, e.EmpFamily, e.EmpFatherName, min(l.LeaveDate) LeaveDate, min(e.EnterDate) EnterDate
from EnterTable e inner join LeaveTable l
on e.EmpName = l.EmpName and e.EmpFamily = l.EmpFamily and e.EmpFatherName = l.EmpFatherName
group by e.EmpName, e.EmpFamily, e.EmpFatherName
```

But you have to choose between MIN and MAX in LeaveDate. In Majid you chose the MIN one and in Yaser the MAX one. Why? I chose the MIN one for both, if it is not the right election, please, give me more data and I update the answer.

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=639d9586886d343fbd53f25e77228046

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  LeaveTable.*, EnterTable.EnterDate 
FROM
    LeaveTable
    INNER JOIN EnterTable ON LeaveTable.EmpName=EnterTable.EmpName and
           LeaveTable.EmpFamily=EnterTable.EmpFamily and
           LeaveTable.EmpFatherName=EnterTable.EmpFatherName
WHERE
    EnterTable.EnterDate>LeaveTable.LeaveDate
```